# How to insert into one table from another table with datatype conversions and value manipulations

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I need to write a query that inserts data into `TableB` from `TableA`.

If data already exists in TableB, do not insert it.

`TableA` is a table with a data imported using `SSIS` package with all fields as varchar datatype.

TableB is a table that has fields of different datatypes.

When doing insert I need to insert data from `TableA` into `TableB`, making sure that `TableB` gets its data in the right format.

This is a `TableA` with data imported with `SSIS` as `varchar` type everything:

[image]

This is a structure of TableB:

[image]

I'm writing the following query:

```
insert into
TableB(Date,Receipt,Description,CardMember,AccountNumber,Amount,YYYYMM)
select Date,Receipt,Description,CardMember,AccountNumber,Amount, 
convert(varchar(4), year(getdate())) + convert(varchar(2), 
month(getdate())) from TableA a
where not exists(select 1 from TableB b where 
b.CardMember = a.CardMember) and (convert(varchar(4), year(getdate()))
+ convert(varchar(2), month(getdate()))) = b.YYYYMM
```

`YYYYMM` column in the `TableB` should contain `YYYYMM` data, where `YYYY` is a current year and `MM` is a current month.

For example:

```
year(GetDate()) = 2015
month(GetDate()) = 7
```

I'm looking for 201507

So, after the query is executed successfully, I have TableB looking like this:

[image]

My query somewhere is wrong and when executing it, I have the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'id'. Msg
>   102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near 'YYYYMM'.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: You are referencing an alias `tt` that wasn't defined anywhere previously.

Comment: I updated SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last field is an int. Don't use varchar functions to populate it like you have:

```
convert(varchar(4), year(getdate())) + convert(varchar(2), 
month(getdate()))
```

Instead, just add ints:

```
datepart(yyyy,getdate())*100 + datepart(mm,getdate())
```

Comment: so, basically, the datatype returned by datepart is integer?

Comment: what about `convert(char(6),getDate(),112)`? If this way is used, should I convert it to integer if i need to compare the result with an integer field?

Comment: You're just asking for trouble. Why go to a char when int uses less data. convert(char(6),getDate(),112) is fine for output to the user. But if it's for a table insert, use integer. If you need to compare them, I would convert the int to a char not the char to an int. Fewer errors that way.